# How can I improve this query? Trying to figure out where to do indexing

Tags: sql, indexing

i've been given a task to improve the below query because it's kinda slow.

```
SELECT 9 AS FieldCount,
A.AccountName AS Field1,
U.FullName AS Field2,
A.City AS Field3,
A.State AS Field4,
A.Zip5 AS Field5,
COUNT(DISTiNCT C.Contact_ID) AS Field6,
COUNT(DISTiNCT L.Lead_ID) AS Field7,
A.Account_ID AS Field8,
A.CreateDateTime AS Field9,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY A.CreateDateTime DESC) As RowNum 
FROM
dynamic_Account A
LEFT JOIN dynamic_Contact C
ON A.Account_ID = C.Account_ID
LEFT JOIN dynamic_Lead L
ON A.Account_ID = L.Account_ID,
static_List AS LS,
static_List AS LC,
static_User AS U
WHERE (A.Account_ID > 0)
AND (A.Source_ID = LS.List_ID)
AND (A.Category_ID = LC.List_ID)
AND (A.AccountSR01_ID = U.User_ID)

GROUP BY
AccountName,
LC.Title,
U.FullName,
A.City,
A.State,
A.Zip5,
A.Account_ID,
A.CreateDateTime
```

Can anyone please give me a pointer of how the joint can be improved or where to put the index? Thanks

EDIT:
Below is the create scripts of the tables that I generated from sql management studio.
dynamic_Account:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[dynamic_Account](
[Account_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[RecordStatus] [int] NULL,
[AttributeList] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[CreateUser_ID] [int] NULL,
[CreateDateTime] [datetime] NULL,
[ChangeUser_ID] [int] NULL,
[ChangeDateTime] [datetime] NULL,
[ViewUser_ID] [int] NULL,
[ViewDateTime] [datetime] NULL,
[InactiveFlag] [bit] NOT NULL,
[Source_ID] [int] NULL,
[Campaign_ID] [int] NULL,
[Comments] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[Parent_ID] [int] NULL,
[Subsidiary_ID] [int] NULL,
[IndividualFlag] [bit] NOT NULL,
[AccountType] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[AccountStage] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[AccountName] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[CompanyName] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[Address1] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[Address2] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[Address3] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[Address4] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[City] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[State] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[PostalCode] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
[Zip5] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
[Zip4] [nvarchar](4) NULL,
[Country] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[DoNotMailFlag] [bit] NOT NULL,
[TerritoryList] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[PhoneNumber] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
[DoNotCallFlag] [bit] NOT NULL,
[FaxNumber] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
[Category_ID] [int] NULL,
[OtherNameList] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[WebSite] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Geolocation] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[OverrideTerritoryFlag] [bit] NOT NULL,
[AccountSR01_ID] [int] NULL,
[AccountSR02_ID] [int] NULL,
[AccountSR03_ID] [int] NULL,
[AccountSR04_ID] [int] NULL,
[AccountSR05_ID] [int] NULL,
[AccountSR06_ID] [int] NULL,
[AccountSR07_ID] [int] NULL,
[AccountSR08_ID] [int] NULL,
[AccountSR09_ID] [int] NULL,
[AccountSR10_ID] [int] NULL,
[AccountSR11_ID] [int] NULL,
[AccountSR12_ID] [int] NULL,
[AccountSR13_ID] [int] NULL,
[AccountSR14_ID] [int] NULL,
[AccountSR15_ID] [int] NULL,
[AnnualRevenue] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[EmployeeCount] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[BusinessDuration] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[Custom_01] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Custom_02] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Custom_03] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Custom_04] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Custom_05] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Custom_06] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Custom_07] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Custom_08] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Custom_09] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Custom_10] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Custom_11] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Custom_12] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Custom_13] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Custom_14] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Custom_15] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Custom_16] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Custom_17] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Custom_18] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Custom_19] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Custom_20] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_dynamic_Account_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Account_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
)
```

dynamic_Contact:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[dynamic_Contact](
[Contact_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[RecordStatus] [int] NULL,
[AttributeList] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[CreateUser_ID] [int] NULL,
[CreateDateTime] [datetime] NULL,
[ChangeUser_ID] [int] NULL,
[ChangeDateTime] [datetime] NULL,
[ViewUser_ID] [int] NULL,
[ViewDateTime] [datetime] NULL,
[InactiveFlag] [bit] NOT NULL,
[Source_ID] [int] NULL,
[Campaign_ID] [int] NULL,
[Comments] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[Subsidiary_ID] [int] NULL,
[Account_ID] [int] NULL,
[ContactName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Salutation] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
[FirstName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[MiddleInitial] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
[LastName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Department] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[JobTitle] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[RoleList] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[DoNotMailFlag] [bit] NOT NULL,
[WorkPhoneNumber] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
[DoNotCallWorkFlag] [bit] NOT NULL,
[CellPhoneNumber] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
[DoNotCallCellFlag] [bit] NOT NULL,
[HomePhoneNumber] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
[DoNotCallHomeFlag] [bit] NOT NULL,
[EmailAddress] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[DoNotEmailFlag] [bit] NOT NULL,
[AltEmailAddress] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[DoNotEmailAltFlag] [bit] NOT NULL,
[ProductInterestList] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Custom_01] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Custom_02] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Custom_03] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Custom_04] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Custom_05] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Custom_06] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Custom_07] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Custom_08] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Custom_09] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Custom_10] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Custom_11] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Custom_12] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[ProductInterestListOld] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dynamic_Contact] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Contact_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
)
```

dynamic_Lead:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[dynamic_Lead](
[Lead_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[RecordStatus] [int] NULL,
[AttributeList] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[CreateUser_ID] [int] NULL,
[CreateDateTime] [datetime] NULL,
[ChangeUser_ID] [int] NULL,
[ChangeDateTime] [datetime] NULL,
[ViewUser_ID] [int] NULL,
[ViewDateTime] [datetime] NULL,
[Source_ID] [int] NULL,
[Campaign_ID] [int] NULL,
[Comments] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[Subsidiary_ID] [int] NULL,
[Contact_ID] [int] NULL,
[Account_ID] [int] NULL,
[LeadDateTime] [datetime] NULL,
[Description] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Details] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[OverrideTerritoryFlag] [bit] NULL,
[SalesRep_ID] [int] NULL,
[SalesGroup_ID] [int] NULL,
[LeadQuality_ID] [int] NULL,
[LeadStage_ID] [int] NULL,
[LeadStatus_ID] [int] NULL,
[ActivityStatus_ID] [int] NULL,
[DisqualifiedReason_ID] [int] NULL,
[ProductInterestList] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Score] [int] NULL,
[Custom_01] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Custom_02] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Custom_03] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Custom_04] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Custom_05] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Custom_06] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Custom_07] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Custom_08] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Custom_09] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Custom_10] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Custom_11] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Custom_12] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[ProductInterestListOld] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_dynamic_Lead] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Lead_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,     ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
)
```

static_List:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[static_List](
[List_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[RecordStatus] [int] NULL,
[AttributeList] [ntext] NULL,
[CreateUser_ID] [int] NULL,
[CreateDateTime] [datetime] NULL,
[ChangeUser_ID] [int] NULL,
[ChangeDateTime] [datetime] NULL,
[InactiveFlag] [bit] NULL,
[ListName] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[Title] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[Parent_ID] [int] NULL,
[DisplayIndex] [int] NULL,
[DefaultFlag] [bit] NULL,
[External_ID] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Custom_01] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Custom_02] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Custom_03] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Custom_04] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Custom_05] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Custom_06] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Custom_07] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Custom_08] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Custom_09] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Custom_10] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Custom_11] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Custom_12] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Custom_13] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Custom_14] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Custom_15] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Custom_16] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Custom_17] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Custom_18] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Custom_19] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Custom_20] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_tmp_static_List] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [List_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
)
```

static_User:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[static_User](
[User_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[RecordStatus] [int] NULL,
[AttributeList] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[CreateUser_ID] [int] NULL,
[CreateDateTime] [datetime] NULL,
[ChangeUser_ID] [int] NULL,
[ChangeDateTime] [datetime] NULL,
[InactiveFlag] [bit] NOT NULL,
[Username] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[EmailAddress] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
[LegalName] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[FullName] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[FirstName] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[LastName] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[DisplayName] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[NickName] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[CellPhoneNumber] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[WorkPhoneNumber] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[FaxNumber] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[JobTitle] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[Department] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[OfficeName] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[Address1] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[Address2] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[Address3] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[City] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[State] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[Zip] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[Country] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[LastAccess] [datetime] NULL,
[Custom_01] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Custom_02] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Custom_03] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Custom_04] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Custom_05] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Custom_06] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Custom_07] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Custom_08] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Custom_09] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Custom_10] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Custom_11] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Custom_12] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo_static_User] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [User_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON
```

Row Counts:
dynamic_Account: 180,000 rows

dynamic_Contact: 310,000 rows

dynamic_Lead: 130,000 rows

static_List: 1300 rows

static_User: 250 rows

I currently have no index on any table.

Comment: Don't mix old-stye join syntax and explicit `join` syntax.  Simple rule:  don't use commas in the `from` clause.   (This won't help performance, but it will help anyone who tries to answer your question.)

Comment: **You need to show us the table and index definitions**, as well as row counts for each of the tables. Maybe your tables are defined poorly. Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly. Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did. Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell. We need row counts because that can affect query planning. If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN` or get an execution plan, put the results in the question as well. If you have no indexes, visit http://use-the-index-luke.com.

Comment: What does "kinda slow" mean?  How long does it take, and how long would you like it to take?

Comment: @AndyLester Hi Andy, i just editted the question with the table structures and the row count.

Comment: Enable the display of the actual execution plan when running the query. This may give you some pointers on what parts of the query are actually slow. There is of course also a tuning advisor that you may use.

Comment: Read through http://use-the-index-luke.com to learn an overview of indexes.  You will probably want an index on any column that is on the right part of a JOIN.  But don't just go adding indexes willy-nilly.  Read to learn about when to use them, and then try some out.

Answer (score 0):

Since your results do NOT include anything from static_List, removing static_List from your FROM clause and using an EXISTS or IN in the WHERE clause will probably help.  Also, you should be consistent with how you join your tables.  Finally, since you don't show anything from the static_List table, including it in your GROUP BY clause doesn't make sense.

You might be able to add indices that speed up your process, but changing your query as follows will probably have the largest impact:

```
SELECT 9 AS FieldCount,
A.AccountName AS Field1,
U.FullName AS Field2,
A.City AS Field3,
A.State AS Field4,
A.Zip5 AS Field5,
COUNT(DISTiNCT C.Contact_ID) AS Field6,
COUNT(DISTiNCT L.Lead_ID) AS Field7,
A.Account_ID AS Field8,
A.CreateDateTime AS Field9,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY A.CreateDateTime DESC) As RowNum 
FROM
dynamic_Account A
LEFT JOIN dynamic_Contact C
ON A.Account_ID = C.Account_ID
LEFT JOIN dynamic_Lead L
ON A.Account_ID = L.Account_ID,
INNER JOIN static_User U ON A.AccountSR01_ID = U.User_ID
WHERE (A.Account_ID > 0)
AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 from static_List WHERE A.Category_ID = List_ID Or A.Source_ID = List_ID)
GROUP BY
AccountName,
U.FullName,
A.City,
A.State,
A.Zip5,
A.Account_ID,
A.CreateDateTime
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, you want to add indexes on the following:

a) joins
b) order by columns
c) group by columns

If you understand what the database is doing, in each of those actions it has to:

a) sort the table to figure out which ones match
b) sort the table in the sequence is needed to return the result set
c) sort the table on what it is grouping by

Indexes and query optimization is a simple subject, but it can contain a lot of complexities.

Also, a primary key automatically creates a UNIQUE index (as a primary key is unique). So you do not need to index this, as long as the PK is there.

This should give you a good starting point.

In your case, I would add an index (the default type is "b-tree") to :

- dynamic_contact (Account_ID)
- dynamic_lead (Account_ID)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like SQL Server to me.

The query returns  180,000 rows, so it will never be extremely fast.

I made few guesses/assumptions about relationships between the tables.

```
WITH
CTE_Contacts
AS
(
    SELECT
        dynamic_Contact.Account_ID
        ,COUNT(*) AS CountContacts
    FROM dynamic_Contact
    GROUP BY dynamic_Contact.Account_ID
)
,CTE_Leads
AS
(
    SELECT
        dynamic_Lead.Account_ID
        ,COUNT(*) AS CountLeads
    FROM dynamic_Lead
    GROUP BY dynamic_Lead.Account_ID
)
SELECT
    9 AS FieldCount
    ,A.AccountName AS Field1
    ,U.FullName AS Field2
    ,A.City AS Field3
    ,A.State AS Field4
    ,A.Zip5 AS Field5
    ,ISNULL(CTE_Contacts.CountContacts, 0) AS Field6
    ,ISNULL(CTE_Leads.CountLeads, 0) AS Field7
    ,A.Account_ID AS Field8
    ,A.CreateDateTime AS Field9
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY A.CreateDateTime DESC) As RowNum
FROM
    dynamic_Account AS A
    INNER JOIN static_User AS U ON U.User_ID = A.AccountSR01_ID
    INNER JOIN static_List AS LS ON LS.List_ID = A.Source_ID
    INNER JOIN static_List AS LC ON LC.List_ID = A.Category_ID
    LEFT JOIN CTE_Contacts AS C ON C.Account_ID = A.Account_ID
    LEFT JOIN CTE_Leads AS L ON L.Account_ID = A.Account_ID
WHERE
    (A.Account_ID > 0)
;
```

`Account_ID` is not `NULL` and it is `IDENTITY` starting from 1, so all values should be positive, so there is no point having explicit filter `Account_ID > 0`. It doesn't make much sense to join to `static_List`, unless `A.Source_ID` and `A.Category_ID` can have values that don't exist in `static_List` (like `NULL`).

**Create indexes**

*These are very important (even if you don't change the query itself):*

- `dynamic_Contact.Account_ID`
- `dynamic_Lead.Account_ID`

These are no so important, but may be useful:

- `dynamic_Account.AccountSR01_ID`
- `dynamic_Account.Source_ID`
- `dynamic_Account.Category_ID`
- `dynamic_Account.CreateDateTime`

**Create foreign keys**

For all relations between the tables.